# Xamarin Studio Build Error on tools version

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin-studio, build-error

When trying to build a simple xamarin.forms program with a StackLayout with a TextLabel, the build error is given referring to the tools version. I believe this may be talking about my VS version but I have VS Community 15.
[the build error given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZogi.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: This is the only error and it seems to throw this error before any code compilation.